# Twilio how to add a PAUSE within a SAY Loop

Tags: java, xml, twilio

I am trying to repeat a SAY message to be played in loop for the entire call duration.

Currently it works. How can I get the message to be played, with a PAUSE of 2 seconds.

This is a sample code:

```
<Response>
<Gather>
    <Say voice="woman" loop="0">This is my SAY message, which is repeating. How to repeat this with a pause of 2 seconds.</Say>
    <Pause length="5"></Pause>
</Gather>
</Response>
```

The twilio documentation mention to use it outside a SAY.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/say
"If you want to insert a long pause, try using the `<Pause>` verb. `<Pause>` should be placed outside `<Say>` tags, not nested inside them."

But with the current implementation, this pause will be never reached.

Can someone guide me on this.

Edit: Trying to use redirect to repeat a message but call gets dropped within 2 seconds once answered. Adding pause is not casuing this, the redirect is, Can someone guide me if there is anything wrong in this?

```
public TwiMLResponse myMethod(){
    TwiMLResponse twimlResponse = new TwiMLResponse();
    Gather gather = new Gather();
    gather.setFinishOnKey("any digit");
    gather.setNumDigits(1);
    gather.setAction("myendpoint");
    Say say = new Say("This message needs to repeat with a pause");
    //Pause pause = new Pause();
    //pause.setLength(2);
    Redirect redirect = new Redirect("myendpoint");

   try {
        gather.append(say);
        //gather.append(pause);
        gather.append(redirect);
        twimlResponse.append(gather);
    } catch (TwiMLException e) {
        LOGGER.warn("exception " + e);
    }
return twimlResponse;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can actually use the [`<Redirect>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/redirect) verb in Twilio to loop a `<Say>` and a `<Pause>`. You could use it like this:

/gather.xml

```
<Response>
  <Gather>
    <Say voice="woman">This is my SAY message, which is repeating. How to repeat this with a pause of 2 seconds.</Say>
    <Pause length="2"></Pause>
  </Gather>
  <Redirect>/gather.xml</Redirect>
</Response>
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: I have edited the question, trying to use a redirect but the call suddenly gets dropped in 2 seconds as you answer it. I have commented the pause in the code for now. Can you guide me on this, if I am doing anything wrong?

Comment: You seem to be redirecting to the same url as your Gather action, you want to redirect to the existing URL you are on. What is the TwiML output of your code?

Comment: Redirect to the same gather action will work in my case as I have a condition check and it will by default return the same IVR reponse.

Comment: Ah, sorry, it's because I put the `<Redirect>` inside the `<Gather>` (only Say, Play and Pause can be nested in Gather). Have edited my answer now.

Comment: Ok thank you for the prompt reply. Also the other solution recommended for adding pause using punctuation's.  I am testing it but seems that they are not getting recognized as a pause. I tried adding periods and commas at the end of my say message. And also tried adding space in between.
Say say = new Say("This is my message with a pause , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , .");
But the message gets played in loop without any pause.

Comment: Oh, that's a good point. That reminds me, it's why I know about the redirect method. At the end of a loop the commas and periods don't get recognised. That's why we recommend the redirect method if you need a longer pause.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. I guess I am going forward with the <Redirect>     appreciate all your help.

Comment: This not working for me. There is no pause. No different with `f'<Response><Say loop="0">{message}</Say></Response>'`

Comment: @NamGVU what isn’t working for you? Are you using a `<Pause>` and then a redirect?

Comment: @philnash I'll make another question to clarify this. Back with you in 5 min.

Comment: @philnash my try on gitlab here, pls have a look https://gitlab.com/namgivu/twilio-start/-/tree/try-pause-between-repeat

Comment: I separate it as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29906937/twilio-how-to-add-a-pause-within-a-say-loop/29916196?noredirect=1#comment113110835_29916196)  as [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63965283/248616)

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation for [`<say>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/say)

> Punctuation, such as commas and periods will be interpreted as natural pauses by the speech engine.

So you can alter your say like this:

```
<Say voice="woman" loop="0">This is my SAY message, which is repeating. How to repeat this with a pause of 2 seconds, , ,</Say>
```

Comment: Without the ability to nest there really isn't another solution.

Comment: The link is dead.  And it doesn't work.  The accepted answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/29916196/26679 with redirect does work.