# Twilio to have pause period when using loop to repeat voice call

Tags: twilio, twilio-programmable-voice

I tried repeating a message in voice call as python code [here](https://gitlab.com/namgivu/twilio-start/-/blob/try-pause-between-repeat/quickstart/make_call.py#L20) which was guided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29906937/twilio-how-to-add-a-pause-within-a-say-loop/29916196?noredirect=1#comment113110789_29916196) but not working i.e. no pause at all whatever number for :length it is `<Pause length="3">`

```
call = client.calls.create(
    twiml = f'''
    <Response>
        <Gather>
            <Say loop="{loop}">{message}</Say>
            <Pause length="3"></Pause>
        </Gather>
        <Redirect>/gather.xml</Redirect>
    </Response>
    ''',
    to    = to,
    from_ = from_,
)
```

Comment: Not clear at a higher level what problem you are trying to solve for. If you explain the core issue and not the issue with your solution, it would help.

Comment: In your code there is no `/gather.xml` that I can find. So what are you redirecting to here?

Comment: I have issue with the code with full shared code repo @Alan. Not sure how clearer I would explain more.

Comment: @philnash Not trying any redirect. Just need a pause before repeat.

Comment: @NamGVU In the question you got this code from, the idea was to use a Redirect to loop the Say and then the Pause. If you want to use that technique, then you need a URL you can redirect to that returns the same TwiML.

Comment: Well thanks @philnash. I don't think user like me need to set up a URL just for a pause in twilio voice loop. Sad.

Comment: Apologies, the normal way to get a pause inside a `<Say>` is with a period or comma `./,` however that isn't recognised at the end of the sentence when you loop. Using a redirect, which you need a server and URL for, is one approach to get around this limitation. I've added a commend to the other answer for getting SSML `<break>` to work for you.

Comment: @philnash Thank you. Tried tht and not working as [code here](https://gitlab.com/namgivu/twilio-start/-/blob/philnash-guide/quickstart/src/make_call.py#L30)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at SSML `Pause`.

[Adding a Pause](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/say/text-speech)

[SSML Break Tag](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/polly/latest/dg/supportedtags.html#break-tag)

I tried out the below, and it worked. Don't forget your `<Gather>` [action url](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/gather#action).

```
<Response>
    <Gather>
        <Say loop="3">This is a message with a pause between loops<break time="3s"/></Say>
    </Gather>
    <Redirect>/gather.xml</Redirect>
</Response>
```

Comment: Thank you @Alan. I'll try ` <break time="3s"/>` and back to you soon.

Comment: Sorry @Alan, <break> not working for my <Say> TwiML command

Comment: I add <break ...> to <Say> command, and try the call. I get command error in the voice call.

Comment: In order [to use SSML you need to use one of the Amazon Polly voices](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/say/text-speech#ssml). Try this with `<Say voice="Polly.Joanna" loop="3">`.

Comment: Thank you @philnash. Will try that again and back to you later.

Comment: @philnash Tried `<Say voice="Polly.Joanna" loop="3">` as code [here](https://gitlab.com/namgivu/twilio-start/-/blob/philnash-guide/quickstart/src/make_call.py#L30). The break `<Pause length="3"></Pause>` still not working.

Comment: @NamGVU I can’t see where you’re adding the `<break>` in that code. Also, when you say it’s not working, what do you mean?

Comment: By "t’s not working" it means the pause not happened when adding `<Pause length="3"></Pause>`

Comment: @philnash Would be nice as you can give me the full <break> line I should added. Thank you.

Comment: It’s Friday night for me right now and I’m not at a computer. Did you check the documentation for `<break>` that Alan linked above? Keep trying at it!